# Add drop shadow to xib view in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview

I have added a card view from a Xib file which when tapped it slides from bottom-up to display the view.

I have am trying to customised the view and a drop shadow to the view which is not working.

The `cornerRadius` works fine otherwise.

[image]

```
func setupCard() {


            menuCardVC = MenuCardVC(nibName:"MenuCardVC", bundle:nil)

            menuCardVC.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.50
            menuCardVC.view.layer.shadowRadius = 12
            menuCardVC.view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            menuCardVC.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
            menuCardVC.view.layer.cornerRadius = 25

            self.addChild(menuCardVC)
            self.view.addSubview(menuCardVC.view)

            menuCardVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - cardHandleAreaHeight, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: cardHeight)

            menuCardVC.view.clipsToBounds = true

            let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(VenueDetailsVC.handleCardTap(recognzier:)))
            let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(VenueDetailsVC.handleCardPan(recognizer:)))

            menuCardVC.handleArea.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
            menuCardVC.handleArea.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)


        }//end setupCard
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below line of code,

```
menuCardVC.view.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: when I remove that line the drop-shadow works but the rounded corners does not?, how can I add the rounded corners?

Answer (score 0):

Since your view hierarchy is simple you could use the following technique. Also, you don't need to use clipsToBounds.

```
let superview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
superview.backgroundColor = .white

let subview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
subview.backgroundColor = .red
// First provide the corner radius.
subview.layer.cornerRadius = 8
// Then provide the shadow parameters.
subview.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
// ...
// Do not clip to bounds since it will clip the shadow.
// ...
superview.addSubview(subview)
```

Comment: When I remove `clipsToBounds` I get the drop-shadow but then lose the `cornerRadius`. I want both?

Comment: Have you tried giving corner radius first and then the shadow as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: yes, I have specified `cornerRadius` first, then specified the `shadowOpacity` parameters and have also removed `clipsToBounds` line. This results in a drop-shadow being displayed but no corner radius. Im struggling to workout why :/

Comment: Try and paste the code in the answer into playground or some random project. You will be able to find the subview with both shadow and cornerRadius.